# how can i retrive column value from parse using objective-c

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

my class name is "User" and i need to get all the values in column "score" and the type of the column is string .. and i need to put all the values in array .. any idea ?

i tired sample code and it did not work and it store only the first value of the column score ..

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"User"];
[query selectKeys:@[@"score"]];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        self.allScores = [objects valueForKey:@"score"];
        NSLog(@"%@",self.allScores);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through the objects array with for loop and add each object in array.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"User"];
 [query selectKeys:@[@"score"]];
  [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            for(int i=0; i<objects.count; i++)
            {
                NSString *string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[objects valueForKey:@"score"] objectAtIndex:i]];
                [self.allScores addObject:string];
                NSLog(@"%@",self.allScores);
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];
```

Try this code. It might help you. Let me know if any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Working

```
 PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"User"];
 [query selectKeys:@[@"score"]];
 [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {

         NSLog(@"valueForKey: %@",[objects valueForKey:@"score"]);
         NSArray *authorList = objects;
         NSLog(@"count = %lu", (unsigned long)[authorList count]);

    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}];
```